# Программа для удобства использования RDP

Tags: windows, администрирование

Подскажите, существуют ли в природе программы, которые облегчают использование удаленных столов в Windows?

Дело в том, что стандартный RDP хорош, когда сидишь на 1 столе.

Если нужно ходить по десятку удаленок, то это очень неудобно.

Какие есть оболочки или утилиты, которые позволяют- это делать удобно? Например, как-то сгруппировать все.

Comment: Сохранить каждое подключение как файл и распихать по папкам не пробовал?

Comment: @donRumata, все равно неудобно, когда нужно держать несколько активных RDP. Все это кучкуется в трее без группировок

Answer (score 2):

Очень рекомендую [Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989)
Удобный инструмент с большим количеством разнообразных настроек.